# Rails joins query -- wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem where I am doing a query across tables in Rails, and Rails is returning an error saying that I am sending an argument.

Here's the controller code:

```
def destroy
  @version = Version.where(number: params[:number]).joins(:packages).where(packages: {name: params[:name]}).all
  if @version.destroy
    render json: {}, status: 204
  else
    render json: { "error": "Version could not be deleted." }, status: 422
  end
end
```

Here's the failing test:

```
describe "DELETE #destroy" do
  context "valid parameters" do
    before { @package = FactoryGirl.create(:package) }
    before { @version = FactoryGirl.create(:version) }
    it "deletes the version" do
      expect {
        delete :destroy, format: :json, access_token: @token.token, name: @package.name, number: @version.number
      }.to change(Version, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "returns 204" do
      delete :destroy, format: :json, access_token: @token.token, name: @package.name, number: @version.number
      response.status.should eq(204)
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the error message:

```
Failure/Error: delete :destroy, format: :json, access_token: @token.token, name: @package.name, number: @version.number
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
 # ./app/controllers/api/v0/versions_controller.rb:19:in `destroy'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `@version` to be collection (`ActiveRecord::Relation`) instead of singular record instance. `destroy` on collections takes argument. If you want to destroy every record in this collection, you can use `destroy_all`:

```
@versions.destroy_all
```

Note: I renamed your instance variable to plural form, so it isn't misleading now.

If you want to find just one `Version` and destroy it, you can do:

```
@version = Version.joins(:packages).where(packages: {name: params[:name]}).find_by(number: params[:number])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! How would I change this?

Comment: @maclover7 to be honest, it depends on what exactly you want from this code. If you want to destroy more than one record in this action, I wrote what you have to do.

Comment: I was planning on having it destroy only one DB record -- I just need to use the where method because find_by doesn't have joins support.

Comment: @maclover7 I updated my answer. Besides, you can always use `first`.